# Как вывести категорию товара в корзине woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В файле корзины cart.php Woocommerce есть таблица, которая выводить данные о товаре (цена, количество и тд). Подскажите, как доработать код таким образом, чтобы в строке с названием товара (product-name), выводилась родительская категория? Код:

```
<td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">              
<?php
if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );   
} else {
echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
// Meta data
echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );
// Backorder notification
if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
}
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в нужный контейнер

```
<?php
$categories = get_terms( $_product->get_id() , [
    'parent'    => 0 // only top level categories
    'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
    'fields'    => 'names'
] );
echo implode( ', ', $categories );
?>
```

[get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Answer (score 0):

В ответе Az Rieil не все гладко, предлагаю мой вывод:

```
$categories = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'type' => 'product', 'parent' => 0) );
foreach ($categories as $categorie) {
    echo '<p>Category: <a href="' 
        . get_category_link( $categorie->term_id ) 
        . '" title="' 
        . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $categorie->name ) 
        . '" ' . '>' . $categorie->name.'</a> </p> ';
 }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]